# Apache/mod_rewrite > Tomcat encoding %26 and "&"

Tags: java, apache, mod-rewrite, jboss

Apache is the front-end to my web app then I use mod_rewrite to proxy the request to JBoss. So far this sounds pretty standard, but the problem I am having is: if I access the app directly through jboss @ `http://localhost:8080/app/page?raw=foo%26bar&page=1`:

```
request.getParameter("raw") = foo&bar
```

If I access the app through Apache @ `http://localhost/foo%26bar&page=1`

```
request.getParameter("raw") = foo
```

So somewhere along the way, the `%26` is lost and replaced with an `&` which chops the raw variable.

This is my Apache rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) \
    http://localhost:8080/app/home?raw=$1 [L,P]
```

The Apache access log shows: `http://localhost/foo%26bar&page=1`

And the rewrite log shows: `http://localhost:8080/app/home?raw=foo&bar&page=1`

But I want the request to be: `http://localhost:8080/app/home?raw=foo%26bar&page=1`

I am pretty sure that this also occurs with slashes `/` too so to me this is some sort of encoding issue. Is there a way to proxy the URL untouched? Can't seem to figure this one out.

**EDIT:**

First thing I would like to say is thank you to Gumbo for giving me some very good suggestions! Based on those suggestions, I have simplified my Apache configuration for testing purposes.

This is what it looks like:

```
ServerRoot "C:/apps/xampplite/apache"
Listen 80

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so

ServerAdmin postmaster@localhost
ServerName localhost:80
DocumentRoot "C:/apps/xampplite/htdocs"
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
LogLevel debug
DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On    
RewriteLog "C:/apps/xampplite/apache/logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9 
RewriteMap escape int:escape
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8080/app/home?raw=${escape:$1} [L,P]
```

Here are the steps I took: Start Apache, go to

```
http://localhost/foo%26bar&page=1
```

in my web browser, stop Apache.

Access log entries:

```
::1 - - [15/Mar/2010:19:17:18 -0400] "GET /foo%26bar&page=1 HTTP/1.1" 403 224 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6"
```

Rewrite log entries:

```
::1 - - [15/Mar/2010:19:17:18 --0400] [localhost/sid#54d160][rid#5e1360/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /foo&bar&page=1
::1 - - [15/Mar/2010:19:17:18 --0400] [localhost/sid#54d160][rid#5e1360/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/(.*)' to uri '/foo&bar&page=1'
::1 - - [15/Mar/2010:19:17:18 --0400] [localhost/sid#54d160][rid#5e1360/initial] (5) map lookup OK: map=escape key=foo&bar&page=1 -> val=foo&bar&page=1
::1 - - [15/Mar/2010:19:17:18 --0400] [localhost/sid#54d160][rid#5e1360/initial] (2) rewrite '/foo&bar&page=1' -> 'http://localhost:8080/app/home?raw=foo&bar&page=1'
::1 - - [15/Mar/2010:19:17:18 --0400] [localhost/sid#54d160][rid#5e1360/initial] (3) split uri=http://localhost:8080/app/home?raw=foo&bar&page=1 -> uri=http://localhost:8080/app/home, args=raw=foo&bar&page=1
::1 - - [15/Mar/2010:19:17:18 --0400] [localhost/sid#54d160][rid#5e1360/initial] (2) forcing proxy-throughput with http://localhost:8080/app/home
```

Error log entries:

```
[Mon Mar 15 19:16:56 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.12 (Win32) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 15 19:16:56 2010] [notice] Server built: Jul 22 2009 11:35:54
[Mon Mar 15 19:16:56 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2324
[Mon Mar 15 19:16:56 2010] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(487): Parent: Sent the scoreboard to the child
[Mon Mar 15 19:16:57 2010] [notice] Child 2324: Child process is running
[Mon Mar 15 19:16:57 2010] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(408): Child 2324: Retrieved our scoreboard from the parent.
[Mon Mar 15 19:16:57 2010] [info] Parent: Duplicating socket 148 and sending it to child process 2324
[Mon Mar 15 19:16:57 2010] [info] Parent: Duplicating socket 140 and sending it to child process 2324
[Mon Mar 15 19:16:57 2010] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(605): Parent: Sent 2 listeners to child 2324
[Mon Mar 15 19:16:57 2010] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(564): Child 2324: retrieved 2 listeners from parent
[Mon Mar 15 19:16:57 2010] [notice] Child 2324: Acquired the start mutex.
[Mon Mar 15 19:16:57 2010] [notice] Child 2324: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Mar 15 19:16:57 2010] [notice] Child 2324: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Mon Mar 15 19:16:57 2010] [notice] Child 2324: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Mon Mar 15 19:17:18 2010] [error] [client ::1] attempt to make remote request from mod_rewrite without proxy enabled: proxy:http://localhost:8080/app/home
[Mon Mar 15 19:17:52 2010] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Mon Mar 15 19:17:52 2010] [notice] Child 2324: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Mon Mar 15 19:17:52 2010] [info] Child 2324: Accept thread exiting.
[Mon Mar 15 19:17:53 2010] [notice] Child 2324: Released the start mutex
[Mon Mar 15 19:17:53 2010] [info] Child 2324: Accept thread exiting.
[Mon Mar 15 19:17:53 2010] [info] Child 2324: 64 threads blocked on the completion port
[Mon Mar 15 19:17:54 2010] [notice] Child 2324: All worker threads have exited.
[Mon Mar 15 19:17:54 2010] [notice] Child 2324: Child process is exiting
[Mon Mar 15 19:17:54 2010] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
[Mon Mar 15 19:17:54 2010] [info] removed PID file C:/apps/xampplite/apache/logs/httpd.pid (pid=1424)
```

Interestingly enough the first entry in the access log shows the %26 and it is gone in the first entry of the rewrite log.

Still puzzled by this one...

Answer (score 1):

Try it with the [*NE* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_flags.html#flag_ne) to prevent escaping of that character:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8080/app/home?raw=$1 [NE,L,P]
```

---

**Edit**    I think I got that wrong. Rather than preventing the value to be escaped you need to enforce escaping. Try it with the internal escape function:

```
RewriteMap escape int:escape
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8080/app/home?raw=${escape:$1} [L,P]
```

Comment: I tried :
RewriteRule ^/(.*) \
        http://localhost:8080/app/home?raw=$1 [NE,L,P]

No luck, the rewrite log entry is the same as without the NE flag. 
Perhaps the flag is in the wrong place?

Comment: That looked promising but still no luck. I increased the log level in Apache/rewrite and discovered something...

The first line looks like this: 

init rewrite engine with requested uri /foo&bar&page=1

Doesn't this mean that we are already working with a manipulated string? Shouldn't it still be: /foo%26bar&page=1 at this point?

Further in the logs we can see the escaping:
map lookup OK: map=escape key=foo&bar&page=1 -> val=foo&bar&page=1

but there seems to be nothing to do because the %26 was already converted to &.

Comment: @user293479: Do you use any other rules?

Comment: Hi Gumbo I have edited my original post and added more information. Hopefully that will be more helpful to you. I have also tried to remove as much as I could out of the Apache configuration to help simplify the debugging process.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8080/app/home?raw=$1 [B,NE,L,P]
```

As should this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8080/app/home?raw=%1 [L,P]
```